# Power failure while docker container was running, unable to start container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had a power failure while my docker container was running.

I wasn't able to start my containers via `docker-compose up`. I tried `docker-compose down` which gives me the following error:
Removing docker_db_1 ... error

> ERROR: for docker_db_1  Driver devicemapper failed to remove root
>   filesystem
>   1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a:
>   failed to remove device
>   d83eae2675e0dae691d45ca4f0a08767bc5b225f335b3562363a83fca7575238:
>   Device is Busy Removing network docker_default WARNING: Network
>   docker_default not found.

`sudo docker-compose --verbose rm db` :

> compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files:
>   ./docker-compose.yaml docker.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths:
>   ['/root/.docker/config.json', '/root/.dockercfg']
>   docker.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
>   compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.11.2, build
>   dfed245b docker-py version: 2.1.0 CPython version: 3.6.1 OpenSSL
>   version: OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017 compose.cli.command.get_client:
>   Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
>   compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Version=17.04.0-ce,
>   ApiVersion=1.28, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=4845c567eb,
>   GoVersion=go1.8, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.10.13-1-ARCH,
>   BuildTime=2017-04-08T18:55:45.235834955+02:00
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <-
>   (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker']})
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list
>   with 2 items) compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker
>   inspect_container <-
>   ('1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a')
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container ->
>   {'AppArmorProfile': '',  'Args': ['mysqld'],  'Config':
>   {'ArgsEscaped': True,
>               'AttachStderr': False,
>               'AttachStdin': False,
>               'AttachStdout': False,
>               'Cmd': ['mysqld'],
>               'Domainname': '',
>               'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
>               'Env': ['MYSQL_USER=chapp', ... compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <-
>   ('e9eba78b88280f2a8c853deee187ac707330eb753c132d7bf47b219ce44d8c0e')
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container ->
>   {'AppArmorProfile': '',  'Args': ['rabbitmq-server'],  'Config':
>   {'AttachStderr': False,
>               'AttachStdin': False,
>               'AttachStdout': False,
>               'Cmd': ['rabbitmq-server'],
>               'Domainname': '',
>               'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
>               'Env': ['PATH=/opt/rabbitmq/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
>                       'RABBITMQ_LOGS=-', ... Going to remove docker_db_1 Are you sure? [yN] y compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker
>   containers <- (all=True, filters={'label':
>   ['com.docker.compose.project=docker']})
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list
>   with 2 items) compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker
>   inspect_container <-
>   ('1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a')
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container ->
>   {'AppArmorProfile': '',  'Args': ['mysqld'],  'Config':
>   {'ArgsEscaped': True,
>               'AttachStderr': False,
>               'AttachStdin': False,
>               'AttachStdout': False,
>               'Cmd': ['mysqld'],
>               'Domainname': '',
>               'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
>               'Env': ['MYSQL_USER=chapp', ... compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <-
>   ('e9eba78b88280f2a8c853deee187ac707330eb753c132d7bf47b219ce44d8c0e')
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container ->
>   {'AppArmorProfile': '',  'Args': ['rabbitmq-server'],  'Config':
>   {'AttachStderr': False,
>               'AttachStdin': False,
>               'AttachStdout': False,
>               'Cmd': ['rabbitmq-server'],
>               'Domainname': '',
>               'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
>               'Env': ['PATH=/opt/rabbitmq/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
>                       'RABBITMQ_LOGS=-', ... Removing docker_db_1 ...  compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {} compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for
>   
>   compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker remove_container <-
>   ('1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a',
>   v=False) compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>
> compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

...

> compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>   compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set() Removing docker_db_1 ...
>   error compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>
> ERROR: for docker_db_1  Driver devicemapper failed to remove root
>   filesystem
>   1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a:
>   failed to remove device
>   d83eae2675e0dae691d45ca4f0a08767bc5b225f335b3562363a83fca7575238:
>   Device is Busy

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sometimes restarting the docker service will allow you to delete those volumes.    Apparently devicemapper is still a bit .... wonky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/1b8aab6f0e543e4ae06f4cb7b803f6383f6aa99f3b63394b0b45264304728b3a`

Answer (score 1):

You can either **remove the container**, like you did or try adding

```
--force-recreate
```

parameter to your run command, this will [recreate the container by force](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).